# How do I make multiple instances in AWS use the same data source?

Tags: amazon-web-services, database

I would like 3 instances to all pull data from the same data source. I want all three instances to pull the exact same index.php for example from an HD or storage medium.

What is the preferred way to do this in AWS? Should I use SimpleDB? Relational DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't want them to be able to change the file:
Put it on S3, put all 3 machines in the ACL for that item, and then let them download it from there.

If they need to write data to the file, you'd have to write some negotiation logic around the uploader that locks it briefly.